# How to find the squared matrix whose results of mulitplication with another matrix is equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, metric-spaces, convex-optimization

I have non-square real matrix $X$ whose size is e.g., $2$ x $6$,  I need to find the square real matrix $Y$ different than $0$ with size $6$ x $6$ such that $XY = 0$.

I have tried this using the [Null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)), which can be found in matlab as follows: `Y = null(X)`, but that matrix $Y$ in this case is not square of size $6$ x $6$. Is there a way to get that square matrix $Y$ such that $XY = 0$ ?

Comment: Ummm... what if $Y = {\bf 0}$, a matrix of $0$s?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, No, I don't want to set $Y$ to be 0.

Comment: Well then pose your question accordingly.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Ok, I will edit it. thank you for your advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already found the null space, the next step is build a $6 \times 6$ matrix where every column is chosen from that space:

$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf y}_1&{\bf y}_2&\cdots&{\bf y}_6 \end{bmatrix} $$

where ${\bf y}_i \in \operatorname{Null}X$. Then, where $X = \begin{bmatrix}{\bf x}_1\\{\bf x}_2\end{bmatrix}$, we have $(XY)_{ij} = {\bf x}_i\cdot{\bf y}_j = 0$, as required.

If you don't care about finding *all* such matrices and only need to find one, then the simplest option is to make all the columns the same.

---

You didn't provide a specific example, so let me make one up. Suppose we have

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1\\2&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the null space is
$$\operatorname{Null}{X} = \{(0,-a-b-c-d,a,b,c,d): a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R\}$$
To pick an element from this space, choose any $a,b,c,d$. Let's keep it interesting by not choosing all zero; say $a=1, b=1, c=0, d=0$. This gives the vector $(0,-2,1,1,0,0)$. We'll use this as our first column. Let's take $a=b=c=0$, $d=-5$ for the next column. So far we have:

$$Y = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-2&5\\1&0&\cdots&\\1&0\\0&0\\0&-5\end{bmatrix}$$

and the remaining columns can be chosen similarly by choosing arbitrary values for $a,b,c,d$. Once again, you could elect to make every column identical. Try calculating $XY$ to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am interested in the first option of your answer which is : If you've already found the null space, the next step is build a $6$ × $6$ matrix where every column is chosen from that space: $Y = [y_1  y_2  y_3  y_4  y_5  y_6]$. but I didn't understand it well. For example., when using null(X) in matlab I get $Y = [y_1  y_2  y_3  y_4  y_5]$, so in that case how can I get $y_6$ ? could you please add more details .thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand how to get $y_i$ from $Null X$.

Comment: @Fatima_Ali I've added an example for you. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Thank you so so so much,  I got it.  But, what's the meaning of that? what does that mean, is there a  proof for that I can read?. . and I think I can set the columns to have a unitary matrix such that $(XY)*(XY)' = I$ where $I$ is identity matrix, right?

Comment: The proof is really just the definition of the null space. The null space, by definition, consists of precisely those vectors whose dot product with any row of $X$ will give $0$. I hope that is clear. If you have further questions (e.g., "what does the null space mean?" or about your unitary matrices), then it would be best to ask them in separate posts.

Comment: OK .. thanks again

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck.