# does the null space have always det equal to 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have a matrix $X$ whose size $2$ x $6$, and I found the square matrix $Y$ whose size $6$ x $6$ such that $X*Y = 0$ following the method described [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143717/how-to-find-the-squared-matrix-whose-results-of-mulitplication-with-another-matr)

In all matrices I got satisfying $X*Y = 0$, I get the determinant ($det$) of matrix $Y$ equal to zero ($det(Y) = 0$). Is that a general case or it exist some matrices $Y$ satisfying $X*Y = 0$ with det differnt than 0 ?

Comment: It sounds like you have chosen too many vectors to be in Y.  You should pare it down to a linearly dependent set.  And Y should not be a square matrix.

Comment: @F If $X$ is non-zero and $Y$ is square with $XY=0$, then it must hold that $\det Y=0$.

Comment: @DougM unfortunately $Y$ must be square in the case I am working on it. Because I need to get the inverse of $Y$. in case if its det is zero, It will be difficult to get its inverse.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you so much..

Comment: Y has no inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column vectors of $Y$ are in the null space of $B.$

If $Y$ has non-zero determinant, then the six column vectors are linearly independent, and thus they are a basis for $\mathbb R^6.$ But that means $Xv=0$ for all $v\in \mathbb R^6.$

This is only possible if $X=0.$

When $X=0,$ of course, we can pick any $Y,$ so the determinant is not necessarily zero then.

This obviously generalizes to when $X$ is $m\times n$ and $Y$ is $n\times n.$

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much. because I need to get the inverse of $Y$, so how to get the inverse of that matrix $Y$ whose determinant is null ?

Comment: Matrices with determinant $0$ do not have inverses. Why do you need to get the inverse of $Y?$

Comment: because I have a vector $d$ multiplied with $Y$ such as $D = Yd$  so I need to get the vector $d$ back.  with using $d_e = D*pinv(Y)$, I don't get the exact solution/

Comment: Yeah, you can’t necessarily get $d$ back. For some $D$ there is no $d.$ For other $D,$ there are infinitely many $d.$

Comment: But, if $D$ is invertible, we will be able to get $d$, right? so is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: If $D=Yd,$ then $D$ is not invertible unless $Y$ is.