# Is there relationship between matrix nullity and rank of null matrix we can build

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Give a matrix $A$ whose size e.g., $m$ x $n$, and $m<n$.  I know the the null space of that matrix is $X$ such that $A*X = 0$. The nullity of matrix $X$ is e.g $r$.  it means the null space I got is a matrix of size $m$ x $r$. As shown [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143717/how-to-find-the-squared-matrix-whose-results-of-mulitplication-with-another-matr), I can build the square $m$ x $m$ matrix $Y$ by taking the values of each column from the null space such that $A*Y = 0$.

My question, what is the maximum rank of $Y$ we can get by taking its value from the null space? Is it always equal to the nullity $r$? or it can be bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank of a matrix $M$ is by definition the dimension of the vector space generated by its columns. If the columns belong to a space of dimension $r$, they generate a space of dimension $\leq r$, whence $rank(M)\leq r$.

Comment: you mean maximum rank of matrix $Y$ in my case must be $r$  since I built $Y$ based on a matrix $X$ whose rank is $r$?

Comment: @Fatima_Ali Exactly. The maximum rank of $Y$ is the dimension of the null-space of $A$.